# Are there standardized values for the turn ratio of transformers?

Tags: transformer, standard

I am simulating a dc battery charger. The circuit contains a step down transformer
[image]

I will need to lower the tension from 311 V (Vp) (or 220 RMS) to 15 V (Vp). One possible option for the turn ratio would be *nprimary=311*, *nsecondary=15*. But I highly doubt I could find practical transformers with this turn ratio. So is there any table/reference where I can find standard (or at least common) values of transformers turn ratios?

Comment: When you look in a list / catalog of transformers, they are typically sorted by ratio, not by number of windings.

Comment: ... and they will be rated in primary and secondary RMS voltage - not peak voltage. Standard secondary voltages will include 6, 9, 12, 15, 18 and 24 V rms with 115 / 230 nominal primaries.

Comment: The number of turns does more than apply a simple ratio - it also indicates how much power the transformer can move from primary to secondary.   Consider your 311:15 transformer idea....  If you used 21 turns on the primary and only 1 on the secondary, you'd get (about) the same ratio.  But you already know that ain't gonna work!  Transformer design is a complicated subject, you're best off just buying one off-the-shelf that delivers the voltage you need and (at least) the current you need.   BTW, you do NOT need to hit 15V exactly in your circuit - You have a regulator.   16V would be ok too.